# How to optimise firefox for full HD wide screen? Webpages often are centred, search results constricted to 1/3rd of the screen width

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, monitor

[image: Google result restricted to the left side]

As you can see, the Google results uses only 1/3rd of the screen width. Often the case with many websites as well. Any fix to optimise Firefox and Chrome to render the pages for Full HD monitors.

Comment: hmm.. I remember there was some firefox extension that used to kinda sort out this issue. Forgot it's name.

Answer (score 0):

For Firefox I found this extension: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/center-pages/

It allows me to position google search page to center.